# How do I print a string in emacs elisp without quotation marks?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In the **scratch** buffer, I enter the following code and run it with Ctrl-J.

```
(defun tt ()
  (setq t1 1.735)
  (setq t2 3.278)
  (format "Test 1 is %f.\nTest 2 is %f.\n" t1 t2))
tt
(tt)
"Test 1 is 1.735000.
Test 2 is 3.278000.
"
```

How can I make it print this, without the quotation marks?

```
Test 1 is 1.735000.
Test 2 is 3.278000.
```

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `insert`:

```
(insert (tt))
```

This will also add nil at the end - the result of insert

Comment: Thank you! :) Now, how do I prevent the "nil" from being printed as well?

Comment: It's meant to be there. Use `ielm` instead of `*scratch*` if you don't like this behavior.

Comment: Sorry for the VERY late reply, abo-abo, but THANK YOU! :)

Comment: `princ` may also be relevant for some folks that find this question.  It's not really the answer to this asker's question, so not leaving it as an answer, but where `prin1` and `print` produce quotes, `princ` does not... which is sort-of on topic.

Answer (score 1):

"Print" how/where?  (If you want better answers then be more precise in your question.)

As @abo-abo mentioned, you can *insert the text in a buffer* (any buffer, which you can display).  You can also show it in the *echo area*, using function `message`.  See also the `pp` family of functions (library `pp.el`, and perhaps [`pp+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/pp%2b.el)).

As far as the double-quote chars are concerned, they are *not part of* the string returned by either your `(format...)` sexp or your function `tt`.  Some uses of `format` do result in `"` chars as part of the string result.  Be aware, for instance, that `%S` has that effect, whereas `%s` does not.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the *scratch* buffer, try to use the *eshell* buffer (e.g. shell within emacs, call it using "M-x eshell" command).
Once in the *eshell* buffer, you can "defun" functions.
You will get results without quotation marks.

(I prefer to use *eshell* as you can recall history using up and down keys)

Regards.